# How to save the content of a textarea using Ckeditor and CodeIgniter?

Tags: ckeditor, codeigniter-3, ckeditor4.x

I'm using Codeigniter with Ckeditor. My problem is that when I submit the content, the data from the textarea is not stored in the database. But when I tried it again it finally did. So the situation is like I have to double click submit button to save it.

I stored the downloaded Ckeditor on a folder named ./Assests/Ckeditor(Sorry for the wrong spelling.I'll fix this later.)

Here's my form in my view folder:

ask_view.php:

```
    <form id="form" enctype="multipart/data" method="post"  onsubmit="createTextSnippet();">


                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name ="title" class="form-control" id="title"  placeholder="Title" required >
                    </div>


                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_snippet" id="hidden_snippet" value="" />

                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Editor</label>
                        <textarea name ="text" class="form-control" id="text" rows="3" placeholder="Textarea" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                     <input type="submit" class="btn "  name="submit" value ="Submit" style="width: 100%;background: #f4a950;color:#161b21;">


                </form>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assests/js/editor.js')?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('text' ,{
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : '<?php echo base_url('assests/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=')?>',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : '<?php echo base_url('assests/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=')?>',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '<?php echo base_url('assests/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr=')?>'
                                    }
                                    );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//code used to save content in textarea as plain text

function createTextSnippet() {

    var html=CKEDITOR.instances.text.getSnapshot();
    var dom=document.createElement("DIV");
    dom.innerHTML=html;
    var plain_text=(dom.textContent || dom.innerText);

    var snippet=plain_text.substr(0,500);
    document.getElementById("hidden_snippet").value=snippet;

    //return true, ok to submit the form
    return true;
}
</script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/knowmore2/index.php/ask_controller/book_add',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {  
               console.log(JSON.parse(data));

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ask_model.php:

```
 public function book_add($data)
    {
        $query=$this->db->insert('article', $data);
        return $query;

}
```

Ask_controller.php:

```
public function book_add(){
        $data = $_POST;

        $details = array();

        $details['title'] = $data['title'];
        $details['content'] = $data['text'];
        $details['snippet'] = $data['hidden_snippet'];
    $details['createdDate']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $result=$this->ask_model->book_add($details);

        echo json_encode($details);
    }
```

The content with html tags should be save in a column named content in the database, but it didn't save in the first click. It only saves on the second one,but the other data are saved in the first like the title, etc. So I get 2 rows of data, one without the content and the other with one.

Database:

[image: database_image]

Comment: Karel, sorry I have to edit 'hidAden_snippet' back because this will cause errors.

Comment: A friend suggest to use delay. I'm still looking a way to use that. Anyone can give suggestions? I really need a solution to this